# Firefox retain the content of an array inside JSF-Viewscoped-Managed-Bean even after refresh the page

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, java-ee-6

This odd behavior only happen in Firefox (specifically Firefox 8). So I have a `dataTable` that I can do `multiple selection`. A submit button, that will display a list of selected items to a `dataList` and to a `dialog`. If the user did not select anything, then a error msg come up asking the user to select something. The dialog will not appear if the user select nothing. The below code does all that. However FireFox behaves oddly if you do these follow:

1. Click to select an item on the `dataTable`
2. Then refresh (F5 or Ctl + R) the page (you can see the selection got clear off)
3. Then click submit, it show whatever I just selected.

This is unexpecting, since the refresh should clear out whatever you just select due to nature of `@ViewScoped` bean. This behavior only happen in Firefox. IE 8 behave correctly for me. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

**Mojarra 2.1 + PrimeFaces3.0 Final + Tomcat 7**

**UPDATE**: I did some debugging, when I refresh page, the value of the array `selectedFoods` become `null`, but for some odd reason, when it get to `public void checkSelection()`, it hold the value of the previous selection. So odd.

Here is my code.

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />  
<p:messages id="msgs"/>
<h:form id="form">  
    <p:dataTable value="#{viewBean.foodList}" var="item" 
                  selection="#{viewBean.selectedFoods}"
                  selectionMode="multiple"
                  rowKey="#{item}">
        <p:column>
             #{item}
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":form:display :dataList" 
                                 action="#{viewBean.checkSelection}"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:dataList id="display" value="#{viewBean.selectedFoods}" var="item"
                    itemType="disc">
        #{item}
    </p:dataList>
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="dialog1" widgetVar="dialog1" dynamic="true" width="200">
    <p:dataList id="dataList" value="#{viewBean.selectedFoods}" var="item"
                    itemType="disc">
        #{item}
    </p:dataList>
</p:dialog>
```

Here is my managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {
    private List<String> foodList;
    private String[] selectedFoods;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        foodList = new ArrayList<String>();
        foodList.add("Pizza");
        foodList.add("Pasta");
        foodList.add("Hamburger");
    }

    public void checkSelection(){
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(selectedFoods.length > 0){
            requestContext.execute("dialog1.show()");
        }else{
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error", "Please select"));
            requestContext.addPartialUpdateTarget("messages");
        }
    }
    //setter, getter
 }
```

Comment: :P If your code can run correctly on some browser, I would say that you didn't do anything wrong. If your server-side code is wrong somewhere, it will appear on all browser ^^

Comment: @Mr.J4mes :D I was wondering if you generate the same result as I did?

Comment: I still haven't tried yet but I will later :P

Comment: FWIW: can't reproduce on FF9. I don't have FF8 at hands.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. What you're seeing is because of something that is supposed to be a feature of Firefox (I was able to reproduce this on FF4). The selection model for `p:dataTable` is implemented with a hidden form field. When reloading a page, Firefox tries to save and restore form field values that have changed so that you don't lose what you entered. You can observe this by adding a `<h:inputText/>` to your view, typing something in the input, and reloading.

I'm not sure that the Firefox team meant for this to apply to hidden form fields, but I figure there's a decent chance that they did. I plan to file a bug report with Primefaces to either initialize the hidden input or to read the input on load to make the `p:dataTable` selection match. Either solution should result in the rendered selection and the hidden selection model to be in sync.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I would really appreciated if you can file a bug report to PrimeFaces.

Comment: Ah right, that field should have an `autocomplete="off"`. @Harry: you can just report yourself as well on http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/

Comment: I went to file the report and it wanted a forum topic to reference, so I posted there: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=17425. I'll have to learn more about autocomplete as it sounds like that's probably the right solution.

Comment: @BalusC: I have submit issue report for PF at http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3263. Thank you guys